# iTextSharp PDF by memorystream and merge it to a list of PDFs without saving

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

This is a very specific question. I am creating a coversheet with data from existing PDFs located on a network drive. I have built an application that will find, sort and then add the coversheet in the first position finally merging them together by group.

However, in order to do this, I have to save the coversheet somewhere so it can then be picked up and merged. I simply insert the new file location into a List of file locations, then it picks them up and merges them in the order I created.

My question is, is there a way to use MemoryStream to create the file in memory, then add it to the rest of the PDFs that are being added by drive location using FileStream? Everything I have seen requires it be saved somewhere before adding. Since I am using a network drive, I would love to avoid saving a temp file that then just gets deleted.

Comment: When you create a `PdfReader` from a stream, the kind of stream doesn't matter as long add it can be read.